# Export longtitude and latitude data in Excel PowerMaps

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, geotagging

PowerMaps is an Office 2013 Excel add-in that uses Bing Maps to plot addresses and create a geographic map from data, and it seems to be a very easy way of geocoding addresses.  I'm wondering if there's any way to access or export the longitude/latitude data it creates from the addresses.

This would be helpful for a number of reasons, such as:

1. Easily correct bad addresses (e.g. run them through an address cleaning program; right now, I can only get Excel to display them in essentially a popup window)
2. Decrease processing time (e.g. I could save out the long/lat so Excel doesn't have to re-geocode all of the addresses if I create another map)
3. Use the geocoded data with other software